# Can i connect DJI simulator without actual device and test only with mobile application and Android studio

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, dji-sdk

I just want to test android application working with the dij simulator with the sample code given in github. But  when i run the application it shows that the product isnt connected. The mobile device and simultor are on the same network and also the android device is connected via usb to laptop . I dont have the remote controller or any dji devices. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately, you do need a DJI product to test. Ideally in the future DJI will allow virtual testing, without need for product. Using the products can be very inconvenient at times, for example when you are trying to test on a bus.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a DJI device to test the android app.